# "Please consider nominating in the current election" banner is shown to anonymous and low-rep users

Tags: bug, status-review, election, notification-bar

If you visit a site that has a running election in the nomination phase ([example](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/), at the time of writing the post), you get a banner with the following message:

> We need your help! Please consider [nominating in the current election.](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/election/1)

The problem is that this banner is shown to anonymous users who might have just landed on a question from a web search. It's also shown to logged-in users who don't meet the minimum reputation amount required for nomination, so they couldn't nominate themselves even if they wanted to.

Comment: It is also shown to those who have already nominated.

Comment: Please fix this - [this is causing problems](https://askubuntu.com/election/8?tab=nomination#comment2421127_1397773) (no, I won't comment farther on that discussion) - although I was wondering why that user got that message. I'd be fine getting that banner, as I'm over 2k, and have a decent number of badges, and I have an OK-ish candidate score... but please don't show this to users with a candidate score of one!

Comment: **Why is this an issue?** 1) It brings awareness that an election is happening since it rarely occurs. Even if they can't nominate themselves, at least they are now aware of elections and can find out more about it if they want to.. 2) Also, anonymous users also includes users who may have not logged-in yet. If the banner is not there they might miss the election entirely.

Comment: @Sam Because it's misleading. I can only imagine users with <300 rep clicking on the link only to be told that they cannot nominate themselves and their reaction being "Huh? Then, why did you ask me to consider nominating myself in the first place?!". Not to mention that the banner **cannot be dismissed**. Re _"awareness"_: Usually, elections are announced in the Community Bulletin anyway. [1/2]

Comment: Re _"anonymous users"_: That's a fair point and I thought about it. Perhaps keep showing the banner to anonymous users but change the wording slightly: "If you have an `[eligible](link to rules)` account, consider nominating in the current election". [2/2]

Comment: AFAIK, this banner is only shown when the original 1-week nomination period (started: 7 Mar) fails to get enough candidates and is currently on another 1-week extension, which may endanger the fate of the whole election. Probably that's also why the text on the banner looks quite desperate. Compare to [english.se] which currently also has an election and is still within the original 1-week nomination.

Comment: While elections are already announced in the Community Bulletin, personal observation has seen that many users missed/didn't even notice, while a site banner looks more noticeable. Thus, the low-rep users: is there any threshold, like what if someone has 299 reps? They may not notice the election since they don't get an inbox notification to nominate, and may also miss the Community Bulletin. The site banner may help them notice about the election, so that they may try to be more active to get enough reps and to nominate.