# Don't show "You did not vote in this election." to users who did not log in or who did not join the community

Tags: feature-request, election

I was seeing this webpage: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/6 and noticed this:

[image]

> You did not vote in this election.

When I did not join the community, it is quite obvious that I cannot vote in the election.

It's the same case with users who have not logged in as well:

[image]

> You did not vote in this election.

The text is irrelevant to a user who does not have an SE account because they cannot vote.

Please consider removing this text or make it more relevant to the specific user.

Comment: Yep, the whole "Your final votes" panel should be removed when not logged in or not having account on that site.

Comment: While I think @ShadowTheKidWizard 's comment is true, you've got to ask yourself how big the chance is to get to that page as a non-registered user? You would have to go through the users tab -> moderators -> click a specific "elected XXXX link". Does it really warrant developers effort to fix something that deep, that is hardly discoverable by any anonymous user?

Comment: @Luuklag I haven't demanded that this should be changed immediately. Developers can take their sweet time to address this issue :)

Comment: @Luuklag people can send the link to their friends, share it on social media, etc.

Comment: Related regarding election message and non-logged users: ["Please consider nominating in the current election" banner is shown to anonymous and low-rep users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377251/241919)